# How to use "openid connect" with servicestack

Tags: servicestack, openid-connect

I am a big fan of servicestack and in our organisation we are considering looking at oauth2 and OpenId Connect.  To get familiar with OpenId Connect i wanted to setup a IdentityServer3 (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) and get servicestack to use it for authenticationa nd authorisation but i am not sure how to do so.

Can anyone tell me how to do this as i assume using OpenId 2.0 provider is not the same.

-- UPDATE --

Found 
https://forums.servicestack.net/t/integration-with-custom-identity-provider/856
so it seems like i am not the only one trying to find out how to make this work. It seems that a lot of things do support it on the dotnet side and it is just servicestack that does not but since i have been focusing on using servicestack based services i really need to work out how to do this in servicestack.

Comment: There is a tutorial on how to connect with OpenId 2.0 https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/OpenId . You can investigate further with a project like https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/SocialBootstrapApi

Comment: yes that is for OpenID 2.0 not OpenId Connect which from what i understand is quite different

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for others looking for guidance, here's roughly what I did.

Created a custom AuthProvider. In Authenticate(), look for id_token. If it's not found, redirect to the openid connect endpoint with client_id, etc.  My openid connect provider is configured to post back to /auth/[name of my provider] which routes to Authenticate().

If id_token is present, I use System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to validate the token (note: I fetch federation metadata from the oauth provider and cache the signing keys).  Capture whatever claims you need and call OnAuthenticated().